# How to go back to the beginning of a loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

My code:

```
b="y"

ol=[]

#operations list

OPERATIONS = ["-", "+", "*", "/"]

op = input ("Please enter your first calculation\n")

while b=="y":



    ops = op.split(" ")

    #add arguments to list

    for x in ops:
        ol+=x

    if ol[1] in OPERATIONS:

        #make sure operator is an operator

        print()

        #make sure not dividing by zero

        if ol[1] == "/" and ol[2] == "0":

            print("Error")

            b = input("Would you like to do another calculation (y/n)?\n")

            if b == "y":

                op = input("Please enter your calculation:\n")

                continue

            else:
                break
        else:

            n1 = float(ol[0])
            n2 = float(ol[2])

            #calculations done here

            if ol[1] == '-':

                calc = n1-n2

            if ol[1] == '+':

                calc = n1+n2

            if ol[1] == '/':

                calc = n1/n2

            if ol[1] == '*':

                calc = n1*n2

            print("Result: " + str(calc))

            b = input("Would you like to do another calculation (y/n)?\n")

            if b == "y":

                op = input("Please enter your calculation:\n")

                continue

            else:
                break



    else:
        print("Error")
```

How do I ensure that the program takes the new operation to the beginning of the loop instead of continuing to print the original calculation?

Comment: are you sure your indents are right on your code snippet?

Comment: yes the indents are right

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your `ol=[]` within the while loop

Comment: Thanks do you mind also letting me know how to ensure that the program doesn't give an invalid operator error all the time (now it does)

Comment: What do you mean? The code seems to work on this end... Could you post a use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is performed using a list of operations `ol` generated from the variable `ops` which is taken by splitting input `ops` by a space.

You can achieve this by moving the `ol=[]` into the loop:

```
b="y"
# Remove ol=[]

#operations list
OPERATIONS = ["-", "+", "*", "/"]

op = input ("Please enter your first calculation\n")

while b=="y":
    ol = [] # Add here
```

However, there is a simpler approach. The variable `ops` contains a list of operations from the `split` (`str.split` generates a list), and you're then copying this value into the list `ol`. Instead you can split the string straight into the variable `ol` as follows:

```
b="y"

#operations list
OPERATIONS = ["-", "+", "*", "/"]

op = input ("Please enter your first calculation\n")

while b=="y":
    ol = op.split(" ")
```

This is neater, as you then don't require the extra `ops` variable.